# Converting css styles to material ui makeStyles

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I had this css styling initially

```
const Root = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;

  @media (min-width: ${(p) => p.theme.screen.md}) {
    width: ${(p) => p.theme.screen.md};
// p.theme.screen.md is 1007px
  }

  @media (min-width: ${(p) => parseInt(p.theme.screen.lg, 10) + 20 + 'px'}) {
    width: ${(p) => p.theme.screen.lg};
// p.theme.screen.lg is 1100px
  }
`;
```

i want to transform this to material ui makeStyle css
i am able to do this much

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: '0 auto',
    padding: '20px',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
  },
}));
```

I can't understand how to change those @media things (mixins), someone please help.
(And don't give me documentation links, i read it, and couldn't understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the breakpoints from theme object to add styles based on width

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: '0 auto',
    padding: '20px',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
    [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
        // if you want to set the md size value
        width:theme.breakpoints.width('md')
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('lg')]: {
        // if you want to set the lg size value
        width:theme.breakpoints.width('lg')
    },

}}));
```

up -> minWidth,
down -> maxWidth

these are the default breakpoints

xs extra-small: 0px,
sm small: 600px,
md medium: 960px,
lg large: 1280px,
xl extra-large: 1920px,

**Edit:** for updating the default breakpoint theme values

you need to pass breakpoints object and its values like below in your theme object which is passed to the ThemeProvider

```
  const theme = {
  ...
  breakpoints: {values: {xs: 0, sm: 600, md: 1007, lg: 1100, xl: 1920}}
  }
```

Comment: how can i edit values of md and lg, bkos for me md is 1007px and lg is 1100px